# PHP 5.4 trying to implement namespaces in project

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a php 5.4 application where I am trying to implement namespaces.

I have a models folder with a model Admin.php in it.

```
<?php

namespace models;

class Admin extends Model
{
    public function getAllContent($lang)
    {
        return some stuff ...
    }
}
```

I have an adminController.php where I do this:

```
<?php

use models\Admin;

class adminController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
        $variable = Admin::getAllContent($this->lang);
    }
}
```

I get this error

> Fatal error: Class 'models\Admin' not found in /.../controllers/adminController.php on line 22

this is line 22 : `$variable = Admin::getAllContent($this->lang);`

Comment: Do you have an autoloader?

Comment: @JonStirling No, is this necessary?

Comment: If you're not wanting to use `require` or `include`s everywhere, then yes.

Comment: @JonStirling okay, how do I implement it? could you guide me the right way?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php or use Composer with an appropriate config.